# Alert - как указать несколько значений?

Tags: javascript

Подскажите пожалуйста, как в `alert()` указать несколько значений через разделитель?

Как-то так:

```
alert("Hello");
alert("Hello" + ":" + "World");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так как вы и написали :)

Если имеете ввиду через запятую, то это невозможно. У [`alert`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/alert) всего 1 необязательный параметр.

Если не хотите через плюсики, то можно с помощью [шаблонной строки](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

```js
alert('Hello');
alert(`Hello:World`);
```

Comment: Блин, действительно работает ))) Я даже не попробовал прежде, чем вопрос задать. Извиняюсь.

Comment: @Staxcelrom если ответ вам помог, то не забудьте его принять пожалуйста